# Consumption of the unemployed

Tags: macroeconomics, reference-request, labor-economics

I am wondering how the consumption of the unemployed varies over the business cycle. We know that wages of people getting fired in busts are higher than wages of people in booms ([Mueller 2012](http://ftp.iza.org/dp6849.pdf)), so there seems to be some variation in the "unemployed" sample over the business cycle.

This surely should have some consequences on consumption of unemployed people over the BC - are there stylized facts on that?

Im looking for stuff like

- The longer the bust, the smaller average consumption of unemployed
- in busts, average consumption of unemployed smaller/larger than in booms